# How in Elasticsearch correctly to filter data between 2 date?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am confused with strange behavior of **Elasticsearch** (version 6.4). I am tring to filter data between 2 date.

When I use such URL:

```
http://localhost:9200/index/_search?q=date_time:[2018-10-27T00:00:00+TO+2018-10-27T23:00:00]
```

The result is empty. However, when I use URL with `epoch_millis` format of that date, it works and return correct result.

```
http://localhost:9200/index/_search?q=date_field:[1540576800000+TO+1540638000000]
```

In Kibana I see this information about `data_field`:
[image]

How in Elasticsearch correctly to filter data between 2 date?

Comment: please provide your mapping

Comment: What you mean? You want to say that first URL is correct?

Comment: We need to know how your date_field is defined in your index mapping

Comment: @ibexit can you check my post again. I add information which I notice in Kibana about `data_field`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You can read your index mapping via GET http:localhost:9200/index/_mapping/_doc yust for the next time ;)

Comment: Thank you for information! It show me this: `"date_time":{"type":"date"}`

Comment: Please try to encapsulate the dates in double quotes like this: date_field:["2018-10-27T00:00:00"+TO+"2018-10-27T23:00:00]"]

Comment: Unfortunatly, it didn't help. No result.

Comment: This should work. May your field name be wrong? You are using two different field names: date_time and date_field . As we know your mapping for date_time already, what is the mapping for date_field?

Comment: It's really strange, bro. In `Kibana` I see the result of this day `2018-10-27`. The `epoch_millis` format of the date I take from Kibana. So the data for `2018-10-27` day is exist in index. But somehow URL don't work.

Comment: But there are two different field names in your examples above. Is this correct? And you say that the kibana mapping info is for data_field... so we have 3 fields in your examples... which one is correct? Maybe you can show us a example document?

Comment: Don't pay any attention to that. I just misspelled it.

Comment: Ok, so which is the choosen one?

Comment: Bro, in fact the the name is `data_time`. I decided to call it as `data_field` in post just for example. That's all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182636/discussion-between-ibexit-and-nurzhan-nogerbek).